# How to fully remove MySQL and phpMyAdmin

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am sorry if this has been posted before. I have been learning the use of MySQL and phpMyAdmin. Having followed an installation guide during an instructional course, I installed the above applications. However, the root user and password for the association between them seems to be incorrect.

I have tried removing and reinstalling, but this issue seems to follow on after the install as if there was a saved file or table containing old information regarding the previous install. Is there a way of fully removing both and all associated tables and files without having to resort to anything too drastic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fully remove MySQL and phpMyAdmin by doing the following:

1. Open your terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and log in as root:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. Stop all MySql services that may still be running:

   ```
   service mysql stop
   ```
3. Remove mysql and all its folders and files:

   ```
   apt-get remove --purge mysql*

   apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y

   apt-get autoremove -y

   apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql

   rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql

   find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
   ```
4. Remove PhpMyAdmin:

   ```
   apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
   ```
5. Autoremove and clean all dependencies:

   ```
   apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
   ```

Comment: Many thanks all, that has sorted it. I have now re-installed and have it working correctly

Comment: @GarethJones I'm glad your problem was resolved...

Answer (score 2):

If that was a production server, removing everything wouldn't be a solution. Probably your problem is related to the `debian-sys-maint` MySQL user - its password or its privileges. The correct solution for this issue is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644435/6543935) on Stack Overflow:

> That’s because Debian has a MySQL account `debian-sys-maint` used for switching on/off and checking status. The password for that user
>   should be the same as stored in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. The file
>   looks like this:
>
> ```
>     # Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
>     [client]
>     host     = localhost
>     user     = debian-sys-maint
>     password = <password>
>     socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>     [mysql_upgrade]
>     host     = localhost
>     user     = debian-sys-maint
>     password = <password>
>     socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>     basedir  = /usr
> ```
>
> If the password doesn't match (for example because you changed it manually) the init script won't work anymore. You should set the
>   password according to the file. So
>
> ```
>     mysql -u root -p
>     # Then type MySQL root password
>     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Remove MySQL

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

Remove MySQL folders

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Delete all MySQL files from File System

```
sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Remove PhpMyAdmin

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

Cleanup system (dependences)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPMYADMIN

1. sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
2. sudo apt-get autoremove
3. sudo ap-get autoclean

MYSQL

1. sudo systemctl stop mysql
2. sudo apt-get remove mysql*
3. sudo apt-get purge mysql